# Remove first columns of every tibble in list in R

Tags: r

I have a list with several tibbles comprising several columns; and I want to remove the first 2 columns in each tibble (not using for loop).

```
 #Example data with tibble and list
 w <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 tibble <- tibble(w, x, y, z)
 list <- list(tibble, tibble, tibble, tibble)

 #Remove the first 2 columns in the tibble
 tibble1 <- subset(tibble, select=-c(1:2))
 tibble1

 #Tried this to remove the first two columns of each tibble in list 
 list1 <- sapply(list, FUN = function(x) subset(x, select=-c(1:2)) ) 
 list1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace `sapply` with `lapply` to get expected output as list

```
lapply(list, FUN = function(x) subset(x, select=-c(1:2)))
```

With `sapply` you need to add `simplify = FALSE`

```
sapply(list, FUN = function(x) subset(x, select=-c(1:2)), simplify = FALSE)
```

---

Another alternative is to use `[` to subset which is shorter and concise.

```
lapply(list, `[`, -c(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
library(purrr)
list %>% map(subset,select=-c(1:2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R method using Map:

```
Map(function(x){x[,-c(1:2)]}, df_list)
```

Data:

```
require("tidyverse")
w <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
tibble <- tibble(w, x, y, z)
df_list <- list(tibble, tibble, tibble, tibble)
```